# Do these two sentences mean the same thing?

Tags: meaning

Do the following two sentences mean the same thing?

> 部下は課長に残業を頼まれました。
>
> 課長は部下に残業を頼ませました。

Answer (score 6):

No, these do not mean the same thing.

> 部下は課長に残業を頼まれました。
>   部下 was asked by 課長 to work overtime.
>
> 課長は部下に残業を頼ませました。
>   課長 made 部下 ask [a third person] to work overtime.

The latter is a "double-causative" sentence involving three people. The former refers to the same event as the following sentence:

> 課長は部下に残業を頼みました。
>   課長 asked 部下 to work overtime.